# Azure mobile service - reading from two tables and return custom response object

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am writing Azure Mobile Service (AMS) API with JavaScript backend named `customertickets` and in the .get function I am attempting to read values from two tables in my  AMS.

The two tables are 'User' and 'Ticket' and I am attempting to retrieve all tickets based on the passed parameter (phonenumber) and  return some statistical data. Additionally, I am injecting a custom return value `item.spname` when looping through the tickets if the ticket satisfy a certain condition (item.parsedjsondata.SPId is not null or empty).

Here is the complete code (ctrl+F 'THIS DOES NOT WORK!'):

```
//Get ticket info by customer phonenumber
exports.get = function(request, response) {
    var phonenumber = request.query.phonenumber;
    var activeTicketsCounter = 0;
    var completedTicketsCounter = 0;
    var canceledTicketCounter = 0;
    var needCustomerRatingTicketCounter = 0;
    var includeCounterData = request.query.includeCounterData;


    console.log("customertickets/get phonenumber: " + phonenumber);

    request.service.tables.getTable('Ticket').read({
        //SEE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406110/how-to-get-system-properties-createdat-version-in-javascript-backend-of-azu
        systemProperties: ['__createdAt', '__updatedAt'],
        success: function(result) {

            //No ticket is found
            if (result.length === 0) {
                console.log("customertickets/get: no ticket found");
                response.send(statusCodes.NOT_FOUND, { message: "customertickets/get: no ticket is found" });

            }
            //return tickets after filtration based on the customer phonenumber
            else {
                console.log("customertickets/get: ticket found");
                var filteredResults = [];
                result.forEach(function(item) {
                    //only tickets with matched phonen number
                    if (JSON.parse(item.jsondata).customerPhonenumber == phonenumber) {
                        console.log(item);

                        //Adding parsed jsondata to item
                        item.parsedjsondata = JSON.parse(item.jsondata);

                        //Adding the name of the assigned spid; only if spid is not null ie. ticket is already assinged
                        if (item.parsedjsondata.SPId) {

                            console.log("SPID", item.parsedjsondata.SPId);
                            console.log("customerId", item.parsedjsondata.customerId);

                            //This works as expected
                            item.spid = item.parsedjsondata.SPId;

                            request.service.tables.getTable('User').where({ id: item.parsedjsondata.SPId.toString(), usertype: "200" }).read({

                                success: function(userResults) {
                                    console.log('result', userResults[0]);
                                    //Does not exist; return NOT FOUND as sp name!
                                    if (userResults.length === 0) {
                                        //This wroks fine and logs the expected result
                                        console.log("customertickets/get: not SPname found", item.parsedjsondata.SPId);
                                        //THIS DOES NOT WORK!
                                        item.spname = "Service Provider Name Not Found";
                                    }
                                    //Record exists; return it
                                    else {
                                        //This wroks fine and logs the expected result
                                        console.log("retrieved spname", JSON.parse(userResults[0].userjsondata).businessData.businessname.ar);
                                        //THIS DOES NOT WORK!
                                        item.spname = JSON.parse(userResults[0].userjsondata).businessData.businessname.ar;
                                    }

                                }
                            });


                        }


                        //ActiveTicketsCounter
                        if (item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_ToBeAssigned"
                            || item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_IsAssigned"
                            || item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_InProgress"
                            || item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_SPDisputed_CustomerNotReachable"
                            || item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_SPDisputed_OutOfScope"
                            || item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_SPDisputed_CustomerCanceled"
                            || item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_SPDisputed_PriceDisagreement") {
                            activeTicketsCounter++;
                        }

                        //needCustomerRatingTicketCounter
                        if (item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_Completed_No_Customer_Rating") {
                            needCustomerRatingTicketCounter++;
                        }

                        //CompletedTicketsCounter
                        if (item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_Completed_And_Customer_Rated") {
                            completedTicketsCounter++;
                        }

                        //canceledTicketCounter
                        if (item.parsedjsondata.ticketStatus == "TicketStatus_CanceledByB8akAgent") {
                            canceledTicketCounter++;
                        }

                        //Testing: it works!
                        item.testing = "Testing Something!";

                        console.log("item.spname before push:", item.spname);
                        //pushing the found item to the list of results
                        filteredResults.push(item);
                    }
                });

                console.log("includeCounterData: " + includeCounterData);

                if (includeCounterData == true) {
                    //After the loop, add the counters to the filteredresults to be returned
                    filteredResults.push({
                        activeTickets: activeTicketsCounter,
                        pendingCustomerRatingTickets: needCustomerRatingTicketCounter,
                        completedTickets: completedTicketsCounter,
                        canceledTickets: canceledTicketCounter
                    });
                }



                response.send(statusCodes.OK, filteredResults);
            }

        }
    });
};
```

My main issue is that `item.spname` is never assigned a value and does not get returned in the response. I can see that the assigned value of `item.spname` which is `JSON.parse(userResults[0].userjsondata).businessData.businessname.ar` logs successfully in the AMS log but it does not get returned in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're not waiting for the result of the many calls to

```
request.service.tables.getTable('User').where(...).read(...
```

to arrive before sending the response back to the client. Remember that almost everything in the node.js / JavaScript backend is asynchronous. When you call `read` on the User table, it won't wait for the result to arrive before executing the next statement - instead, it will queue the operation so that when the response is available, it will be executed.

To fix this you'll need to make all `read` calls to the users table, and only after you've got all the callbacks is when you can call `response.send`.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is clear to me now. But how do I wait until all 'read' calls are done? Placing the `response.send` inside the `request.service.tables.getTable('User').where(...).read()` will not resolve my issue because I am executing  `request.service.tables.getTable('User').where(...).read()` multiple times inside `result.forEach(function(item){..}) `

Comment: There are a few ways you can do that. You can have a counter (in a variable declared outside of the `foreach` loop) that is incremented for every new response, and once it reaches the number of iterations in the loop you can respond; or you can use an indexed loop, like the one shown in the post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/09/11/supporting-complex-types-in-azure-mobile-services-clients-implementing-1-n-table-relationships.aspx (look for the `insertNext` function).